# Different LINQ Answer in VS 2010 and VS 2012

Tags: linq, ienumerable, lazy-evaluation

The following gives answer as 1 in VS 2010 and 2 in VS 2012. I personally think it should be 2. I am not sure what's going on here.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;

namespace _335ExamPreparation
{
    public class Doubts
    {
        int[] nums = { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };
        int[] divisors = { 7, 10 };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Doubts d = new Doubts();
            d.func();
        }

        public void func()
        {
            var m = Enumerable.Empty<int>();
            foreach (int d in divisors)
            {
                m = m.Concat(nums.Where(s => (s % d == 0)));
            }

            int count = m.Distinct().Count();
            Console.WriteLine(count);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Resharper warning: Access to modified closure

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you're seeing is the result of two different applications of `foreach`.  The behavior was changed in VS 2012.  See [this article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/kathleen/archive/2012/07/03/lifting-foreach-breaking-change-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx).

The difference between the two involves the scope and lifetime of the `d` variable in the `foreach` loop.  Before VS 2012, there was only one `d` variable, so what this means is that you are creating two copies of a closure (`s => (s % d == 0))`) that both reference the *same* `d`.  After the loop finishes being evaluated, `d` is 10.  When you execute the query by calling `.Distinct().Count()`, both closures will see a value of 10 for `d`.  This is why the count is 1 on VS 2010.

VS 2012 generates a different variable for each iteration<sup>1</sup>, so each closure will see a *different* instance of the `d` variable, the one that corresponds to that particular iteration.

This is roughly the code that VS 2010 generates:

```
int d;
for (int _index = 0; _index < divisors.Length; ++_index) {
    d = divisors[_index];
    m = m.Concat(nums.Where(s => (s % d == 0)));
}
```

And this is roughly what VS 2012 generates:

```
for (int _index = 0; _index < divisors.Length; ++_index) {
    int d = divisors[_index];
    m = m.Concat(nums.Where(s => (s % d == 0)));
}
```

The difference between these two should be readily apparent.

If you want to get the same behavior no matter which VS version, then *always* copy your iteration variable:

```
foreach (int d in divisors)
{
    var copy = d;
    m = m.Concat(nums.Where(s => (s % copy == 0)));
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically, only if the iteration variable is referenced in a closure.  If it's not then there is no need to make a copy as this only affects closure semantics anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info bro. Doubts were cleared in and out.

Comment: It's more related to the compiler version then it is to VS, the change happened in C# 5.0: http://kristofmattei.be/2013/04/26/foreach-now-captures-variables-access-to-modified-closure/